# How to display previous value on Min Miles text field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

[image]

I want to display a previous value on Min Miles and that should not be editable. I want like

1. Default value of Min Miles is 0.
2. When I click on Add More Range then In the new form - Min Value should be Max Value of Previous Form.

I am using semantic form for. Please Help Me. How can I do this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your second question, and assuming that the new form appears through javascript, without page reloading, you can grab the
    field value with javascript and use it as the default value for the
    new field. The "add new range"

> Something Like
>    function getvalue(){
>       var inputTypes_max = [],inputTypes_min = [],inputTypes_amount = [];

```
$('input[id$="max_miles"]').each(function(){
  inputTypes_max.push($(this).prop('value'));
});

$('input[id$="amount"]').each(function(){
  inputTypes_amount.push($(this).prop('value'));
});

var max_value_of_last_partition = inputTypes_max[inputTypes_max.length - 2]

var amount_of_last_partition = inputTypes_amount[inputTypes_amount.length - 2]
if (max_value_of_last_partition == "" || amount_of_last_partition == "" ){

  alert("Please Fill Above Details First");
}else{
  $("#add_more_range_link").click();
  $('input[id$="min_miles"]').each(function(){
    inputTypes_min.push($(this).prop('id'));
  });
  var min_id_of_last_partition=inputTypes_min[inputTypes_min.length - 2]
  $("#"+min_id_of_last_partition).attr("disabled", true); 
  $("#"+min_id_of_last_partition).val(parseInt(max_value_of_last_partition) + 1)
 }
```

}

I have Used Jquery's End Selector In a loop to get all value of max and amount field as per your form and get the ids of your min_miles field and then setting that value of your min_miles as per max_miles

It worked For me hope It works For You.

Answer (score 0):

Default value of a field can just be passed in the form builder as a second parameter:

```
...
f.input :min_miles, "My default value"
```

Of course I do not know your model structure but you get the idea.

Regarding your second question, and assuming that the new form appears through javascript, without page reloading, you can grab the field value with javascript and use it as the default value for the new field. The "add new range" click will be the triggerer for the value capture.

Something like (with jQuery):

```
var temp_value = '';
$('#add_more_range').click(function(){
  temp_value = $('#my_form1 #min_miles').value();
  $('#my_form2 #max_miles').value(temp_value); 
});
```

Again I am just guessing the name of the selectors, but the overall approach should work.

If you are also adding dinamically to the page the "Add new range" buttons/links, then you should delegate the function in order to be inherited also for the so new added buttons:

```
$('body').on('click', '#add_more_range', function(){...});
```